# Unity5 OnTriggerEnter2D not called after collision (2D game)

Tags: c#, 2d, collision-detection, unity-game-engine

I'm **brand** new to Unity3D 5 and I'm having issues with my first 2D game involving collision detection. My moving object is a ball and has Rigidbody2D and CircleCollider2D. My stationary "collider or trigger" is a BoxCollider and has a script attached. The OnTriggerEnter2D should be fired when the ball passes through the stationary box. I've also tried OnCollisionEnter2D but I'm fairly certain I should use OnTriggerEnter2D because my stationary box is marked as a trigger.

My code:

```
public class LoseCollider : MonoBehaviour {

public LevelManager levelManager;

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    print("collide");
    levelManager.LoadLevel("Lose");
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D trigger)
{
    print("trigger");
    levelManager.LoadLevel("Lose");
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    print("collide");
    levelManager.LoadLevel("Lose");
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider trigger)
{
    print("trigger");
    levelManager.LoadLevel("Lose");
}
}
```

As you can see I'm testing all variations and none are being called. Here are my Unity properties for my objects:

[image: Ball]

And

[image]

I'm sure I'm missing something simple if anyone can please point it out to me.

Comment: use boxcollider2D

Comment: @CristianoSoleti Put that as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are going to to use `OnTriggerEnter2D`, you must also use a 2D Collider. You are currently using `BoxCollider` as shown in your second screenshot.

Change that to `BoxCollider2D` and your Collision callback functions should be called.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it and makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already solved it, but I ran into the same problem and found your post. I was using the correct 2D collider, I was missing the Ridgedbody 2D component. It took me a while to find that so I wanted to add it here in case someone else comes across the same problem.